# How can I stop navigation property self reference?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have 2 entities with one to many association with navigation properties. Lazy loading disabled.

```
 var det = db.Detail.Include(m=>m.Master);
```

The above statement also includes Master's navigation property "Detail" (self reference).

For each instance of Detail I have a nested Master which has a nested list of associated Details...

How can I stop this recursion? 
I dont want to retreive Master's navigation properties.

Thanks.

Comment: You aren't "retrieving" `Master`'s navigation properties. Instead, what is happening is that EF is filling the `master.Details` navigation property by looking at the `Detail` objects in memory. You can verify this by running a profiler on your database server. Knowing that, is this still a problem for you?

Comment: Knowing this, the only problem would be bandwidth. Redundant data is being transmitted, specially when "Detail" has significant amount of columns and records...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a recursion. EF only loads the `Detail` entities and because of your `Include` the related `Master` entities. The `Detail` entity you see in the navigation property of the loaded `Master`s is the `Detail` entity that has been loaded as the parent. EF puts this object graph together automatically after the entities have been loaded into the context. It's called *relationship fixup* and you cannot stop this.

Comment: You can prevent this by not loading the entities into a context. Whether that's a good idea depends on the reason for this question.

Comment: @hvd: You would have to avoid using `Include` then. Even when using `AsNoTracking` it will fixup the object graph. You had to use a projection `db.Detail.AsNoTracking().Select(d => new { Detail = d, Masters = d.Masters })` and then iterate through the result and set `Detail.Masters` manually. This way you had one roundtrip and `Detail.Masters` populated with `Master.Detail` set to `null`. I don't know another way.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of `from d in db.Detail select new { d.Field1, d.Field2, ..., Master = new { d.Master.Field1, d.Master.Field2, ... } }`, which does not create `Detail` or `Master` objects. But based on nonino's comment on the question, that wouldn't be a good idea here.